# How to store Value of NSDictionary to NSMutableArray in loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am fetching data from database and i will get same data which is last in database. how to store a dictionary value in nsmutable array.

Here is my code !!

```
  - (NSDictionary *) getPreparedAllRow
 {

NSMutableDictionary *dRow=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

int counter=0;
while(sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    int Column_Count = sqlite3_column_count(statment);
    if(Column_Count >= 1)
    {

        for(int count =0 ; count < Column_Count ; count++)
        {
            [dRow setObject:[self columnValue:count] forKey:@(sqlite3_column_name(statment, count))];
            //dRow [ @(sqlite3_column_name(statment, count))] = [self columnValue:count];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",dRow);
    [data insertObject:dRow atIndex:counter];
    counter++;
    NSLog(@"%@",data);
}
NSLog(@"%@",data);
return dRow;
 }
```

when count all data records 9 counter variable. and all data are overwrite with the last data.

here is my log.

```
 (
    {
     "Id" = 1;
    "Name" = Priyank;
},
    {
     "Id" = 1;
    "Name" = Priyank;
},
    {
     "Id" = 1;
    "Name" = Priyank;
},
    {
     "Id" = 1;
    "Name" = Priyank;
},
    {
     "Id" = 1;
    "Name" = Priyank;
},
    {
     "Id" = 1;
    "Name" = Priyank;
},
    {
     "Id" = 1;
    "Name" = Priyank;
},
    {
     "Id" = 1;
    "Name" = Priyank;
},
    {
    "Id" = 1;
    "Name" = Priyank;
}
```

)

Comment: You're only creating one dictionary, so you keep storing it again and again and again.  (Understand that you only store the *pointer* to the dictionary in the array.  The dictionary is not "copied" into the array.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new NSMutableDictionary *dRow on every iteration:

```
- (NSDictionary *) getPreparedAllRow
 {

//NSMutableDictionary *dRow=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

int counter=0;
while(sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    int Column_Count = sqlite3_column_count(statment);

    NSMutableDictionary *dRow=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    if(Column_Count >= 1)
    {

        for(int count =0 ; count < Column_Count ; count++)
        {
            [dRow setObject:[self columnValue:count] forKey:@(sqlite3_column_name(statment, count))];
            //dRow [ @(sqlite3_column_name(statment, count))] = [self columnValue:count];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",dRow);
    [data insertObject:dRow atIndex:counter];
    counter++;
    NSLog(@"%@",data);
}
NSLog(@"%@",data);
return dRow;
 }
```

And I think that you want to return the NSMutableArray*??  maybe you have an error there too...

Answer (score 0):

Actually Return Type should be array and there is no need of counter variable, Try this:

```
- (NSArray *)getPreparedAllRow
 {


NSMutableArray *data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

while(sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dRow=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    int Column_Count = sqlite3_column_count(statment);
    if(Column_Count >= 1)
    {

        for(int count =0 ; count < Column_Count ; count++)
        {
            [dRow setObject:[self columnValue:count] forKey:@(sqlite3_column_name(statment, count))];
            //dRow [ @(sqlite3_column_name(statment, count))] = [self columnValue:count];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",dRow);
    [data addObject:dRow];
    NSLog(@"%@",data);
}
NSLog(@"%@",data);
return data;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a NSDictionary with some values stored in it, the try using this statement. This will automatically take particular key values into that array.

```
arrayName = [dictionaryName valueForKey:@"keyName"];
```

Or you can try this,

```
[arrayName addObject:[dictionaryName objectForKey:@"keyName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

First up all create one NSObject class called as

/**** #import "StudentDTO.h" ******/

```
 @interface StudentDTO : NSObject
    {
        int ID;
        NSString *stu_name;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, readwrite) int ID;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stu_name;

@end
```

/**** #import "StudentDTO.m" ******/

```
@implementation StudentDTO

@synthesize ID,stu_name;

@end
```

**////Now in your code Import #import "StudentDTO.h"**

```
-(NSDictionary *) getPreparedAllRow

 {

NSMutableDictionary *dRow=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
int counter=0;
while(sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
   int Column_Count = sqlite3_column_count(statment);
    if(Column_Count >= 1)
    {

        for(int count =0 ; count < Column_Count ; count++)
        {
            [dRow setObject:[self columnValue:count] forKey:@(sqlite3_column_name(statment, count))];
            //dRow [ @(sqlite3_column_name(statment, count))] = [self columnValue:count];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",dRow);
    StudentDTO *studto=[[StudentDTO alloc]init];
    studto.ID=[dRow objectforkey:@"Id"];
    studto.stu_name=[dRow objectforkey:@"Name"];[data addobject:studto];
    counter++;
    NSLog(@"%@",data);}NSLog(@"%@",data);return dRow;

 }
```